# Post-apocalyptic (horror) movie with mankind surviving in a bunker

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror, post-apocalyptic

I'm trying to recall a specific post-apocalyptic movies. It is kinda like *The Colony* (2013), where mankind is surviving in a bunker. I can't remember if it is due to climate change or nuclear fallout but I do remember it was a group of people trying to survive.

I remember there was some really demented people, women were scarce so much in fact that they were raping this one woman so much that she had (expired..). they were fighting for their lives and there were cannibals in the movie.

Also there was a good guy like Laurence Fishburne who died in the beginning and a bad guy like Bill Paxton and there was a young hero like Kevin Zegers.... But it is none of these actors and I have watched The Colony over and over.

Comment: Hi there. Some more info that you could possibly [edit] in - when would this movie had been made? Were the cannibals _inside_ the bunker already or were they monsters outisde? Actually - did people leave the bunker at some point?

Comment: It reminds me of a French movie I have had described, but I can't find it with a brief Google search.

Comment: @Klaus you're thinking of [*Le Dernier Combat*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le_Dernier_Combat). It's post-apo and women are scarce, but there are no cannibals and I think would have remembered it being in black and white with zero dialogue

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like *[The Divide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Divide_(2011_film))* (2011).

A small group of survivors takes refuge inside the basement of an apartment building following some kind of apocalyptic event. Various power struggles ensue as the situation deteriorates. One of the female survivors joins with a group of men, the self appointed alpha males, to ensure protection and a share of the rapidly dwindling supplies they have. Eventually the lack of food and her repeated sexual exploitation causes her death at their hands.

Comment: Could you explain how this matches the details listed in the question?

Comment: Added extra detail.